# how to link own css/php file in Typo3 file.inc

Tags: php, css, typo3

sorry for the bother.
I've already searched for a while but since i'm not practical with TYPO3, either i don't understand if what i find is useful or i don't search well cause i don't know what to search. I ask sorry in advance.

I've this project to do for my university, and i've been asked to implement a form with the underline Database to registry peole who enters in the Department and ask for them to activate the card.

I only use .inc files in fileadmin/phpinclude folder to create my pages.
**What i'm not able to do is to link my own css and php files.**

For example i have form.inc which should use my style.css i tried to link it through the classical html way:

```
<link href="fileadmin/php_include/accessi/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but it doesn't work , instead, if i use an "in-page" css it works.
i think i'll have the same problem with a php file.

Could anyone, please, explain what i should do?

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to work aside of TYPO3: include files are not very usual for TYPO3. so it's not clear what you are doing. Maybe you should explain how do you include your `.inc` files. as hendrikg explained: an extension would be the typical solution for TYPO3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a little unsual to use external php files for building forms in TYPO3. The usual way would be to write an extension or use TYPO3's own native form component.

And the usual way to include css files in TYPO3 would be to include it via typoScript: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecss-array

But if you want to do it in the way you described above, it sounds pretty much like the uri to your css file is wrong. Maybe it is because you are using a relative url. Checkout the DEV-Tools of your browser and see what HTML response code the call the css resource returns.  In Chrome you can see that on the "network" tab. You will also see there what absolute uri the browser called and maybe you get a clue what is wrong with your uri.